# Not able to give owner access from classic service administrator role

Tags: azure, role-based-access-control

I am learning about Azure. I am using a personal account and want to give my Azure Entra ID, `Owner` access. My current role is the classic `Service Administrator`.

[image]

But while trying to add role assignments, I'm not able to see either `Owner` or `Contributor` in the options, though `Reader` is available. According to documentation

> The Service Administrator and Co-Administrators are assigned the Owner role at the subscription scope

So what am I missing? Any help is appreciated

P.S. - I am trying to give access to Azure Entra ID because I am experimenting with the credential passthrough option in Azure Databricks. To enable that, Azure Entra ID account needs role based access separately and classic Service Administrator access is not enough.

Comment: Did you check whether the roles are present under like **Privileged administrator roles** [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/8j405Ck.png). *Go to Subscriptions -> Select your subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add -> Add role assignment -> Click on Privileged administrator roles*.

Comment: Yeah, it was there. Could you please add it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Yes sure posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: By default, the service administrator role is assigned to the user who is the account administrator.

- The service administrator role has the owner level access at the subscription level.
- Hence the owner has the access to assign roles to any users.
- The service administrator has complete/full access to the Azure Portal.

*I have Service Administrator role:*

[image]

The owner and contributor roles will be present under the **Privileged administrator roles**:

*Go to Subscriptions -> Select your subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add -> Add role assignment -> Click on Privileged administrator roles*.

[image]

***By having the Service Administrator role, I am able to assign owner and contributor role to the user:***

[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure roles, Microsoft Entra roles, and classic subscription administrator roles | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#classic-subscription-administrator-roles)

Comment: Could you also check another question - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77649022/same-user-comes-twice-in-azure-databricks)

Comment: Yes sure I will check