# Same user comes twice in Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I am new to Azure. I am using a personal account and was learning about Azure Databricks, so I created a free-trial account and one thing I noticed is that it created two users, one using my email id and the other using the user principal name of my Entra ID.

[image]

I want to know is there any reason behind this or is this just a random thing?

Comment: The users `ruk_gmail.com#EXT#@rukgmail.onmicrosoft.com` and `ruk@gmail.com` are both same users but different sign-in method. The user `ruk_gmail.com#EXT#@rukgmail.onmicrosoft.com` is the Azure AD user and the `ruk@gmail.com` is the Microsoft Account user.

Comment: What is the meaning of external user, I have a personal account and there is only one user which is me. And this `dv_gmail.com#ext#..` is the user principal name in my azure active directory. Why is it being treated as guest?

Comment: The dv_gmail.com#ext# is considered as Microsoft Account and the member of the tenant not the guest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: The users  `user_gmail.com#EXT#@usergmail.onmicrosoft.com` and `user@gmail.com` are both same users but different sign-in method. The user  `user_gmail.com#EXT#@usergmail.onmicrosoft.com` is the Azure AD/work or school account user and the `user@gmail.com` is the Microsoft Account user.

- In Azure Databricks it created two users that is you can use both sign-in methods *(Personal Microsoft Account/Work or school account)* to access the workspace and its by default.
- The users can have both the sign-in methods, user can use either Personal Microsoft Account or the Work/School account.
- Personal Microsoft Accounts are like *@gmail.com @hotmail, @outlook* etc. Work/School accounts have **`.onmicrosoft.com`** as their domain.

[image]

**Work or School accounts** are created by the organization which uses Azure AD for the authentication and authorization.

**Personal Microsoft accounts** provides authentication and authorization to Microsoft's consumer services.

The **`dv_gmail.com#ext#`** is considered as Microsoft Account and the member of the tenant, not as the guest:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Personal Microsoft account and a work or school account? - Microsoft Community Hub](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/what-s-the-difference-between-a-personal-microsoft-account-and-a/ba-p/2241897) by Sonia Cuff